# Use pre-filtering in Kibana on Visualize/Dashboard using Query string syntax

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I created a bar chart with average price rate per day. However, I want to exclude all prices that are below the value 1, before calculating the average.

Let's consider this sample data

```
Price rate
1.0
10.0
11.0
10.5
```

So, if I calculate average price as I do now, the following formula will be applied:  `(1 + 10 + 11 + 10.5) / 4`

But I want to calculate the average as follows: `(10 + 11 + 10.5) / 3`

How can I do this pre-filtering in Kibana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `price:>1` in Kibana search. Refer [Query string syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax).